# Is there is any way to push my database changes to github using git bash?

Tags: mysql, git

Is there is any way to upload my database with changes to Github? I found a [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/can-you-upload-mysql-databases-on-github) which says upload total backup SQL files to live, Is that only way?

Comment: Usually frameworks ORM have capability to manage database schemas and seeds (data), if you use framework you should use its ORM to manage database changes and schema, that way you can manage to push and update database changes using git.

Comment: Yes, I am using Codeigniter framework. Which not support DB migration in V3.

Comment: I suggest then to go with @CodeBRKR solution, just export your database and manage it under git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the database as a sql file and push the same to github using git bash.

Thanks.

Comment: I think, This is the only way to store database changes in git. If anyone working with the latest framework, Please Look @mamoun-othman command